# Do you have to watch all of the content in a memory that is on the Pensieve before bringing your head back from the Pensieve?

Tags: harry-potter

Do you have to watch all of the content in a memory that is on the Pensieve before bringing your head back up from the Pensieve?

Answer (score 3):

### No

It is clear that you can leave a memory in the middle. for example in Snape's memory in Chapter Twenty-Eight of *Order of the Phoenix*:

> But whether James really did take off Snape’s pants, Harry never found out. A hand had closed tight over his upper arm, closed with a pincerlike grip. Wincing, Harry looked around to see who had hold of him, and saw, with a thrill of horror, a fully grown, adult-sized Snape standing right beside him, white with rage.
>
> “Having fun?”
>
> Harry felt himself rising into the air. The summer’s day evaporated around him, he was floating upward through icy blackness, Snape’s hand still tight upon his upper arm. Then, with a swooping feeling as though he had turned head over heels in midair, his feet hit the stone floor of Snape’s dungeon, and he was standing again beside the Pensieve on Snape’s desk in the shadowy, present-day Potions master’s study.